# source your enironment - meaning , and version compatibility

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello and thanks in advace,
i read the tutorials for ros, and everything works, but i've got two questions.
1.what is the actual meaning of "source your enviornment"?
2.i find this page in the tutorial that is written for groovy distro, is it perfectly compatible for indigo with the change of groovy to indigo any place its written?  here is the adress: wiki.rog.prg/catkin/tutorials/workspace_overlaying

thanks.

s

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221874/source-your-enironment---meaning-,-and-version-compatibility/) by [shai2go](https://answers.ros.org/users/25235/shai2go/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. It basically means to setup your environment variables. This is usually done by sourcing a setup.sh file that is provided by ROS/catkin or other tools.
2. Workspace overlaying should work the same in all catkin systems, i.e., groovy and indigo.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shai2go](https://answers.ros.org/users/25235/shai2go/) on 2015-12-02**:
thanks! so if i understand correctly, it just created shortcuts for my linux environment that will help me refer the stuff that i build?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-12-02**:
basically yes